# Injecting javascript with Cordova/PhoneGap

Tags: cordova, code-injection

I'm trying to develop a multi-platform application with Phonegap. This application should allow the user to freely navigate across various websites ( even among websites that do not have) and, during the navigation, should collect some statistical information.
So, I must inject in EVERY visited page some javascript code. There is a way to force Cordova webview to always include my javascript?

To clarify my purposes, I'd like to to something like this: http://lexandera.com/2009/01/injecting-javascript-into-a-webview/ , but inside a PhoneGap project, so I can develop the application on several mobile OS.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can load the websites inside the inAppBrowser view using the inAppBrowser plugin. And then inject javascript.

code example:

```
var ref = window.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes');
ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function() {
    ref.executeScript({file: "myscript.js"});
});
```

See the inAppBrowser documentation for more details.